# Header and footer not displayed on pages

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to display a *header* and *footer* on each page/route in my app.

`<header>` and `<footer>` are both components with a html view defined, and they are correctly displayed in templates without a `<router-outlet>` tag present.

But when used in conjuction with a `<router-outlet>`

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/component/login.component";
import { DemoPageComponent } from "./demo_page/demo_page.component";
import {TaskPageComponent} from "./task/component/task_page.component";
import {
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HashLocationStrategy,
    LocationStrategy,
    Router,
    RouteConfig,
    ComponentInstruction
} from 'angular2/router';
import {Header} from "./components/core/header/header.component";
import {HeaderSecondary} from "./components/core/header_secondary/HeaderSecondary";
import {Footer} from "./components/core/footer/footer.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Header, HeaderSecondary, Footer],
    template: `
    <header></header>
    <header-secondary></header-secondary>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer></footer>
    `
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Root', redirectTo: ['Login'] },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/demoPage', name: 'DemoPage', component: DemoPageComponent },
    { path: '/tasks', name: 'TaskPage', component: TaskPageComponent }

])

export class App {
    constructor(public router: Router) { }
}
```

the header/footer views aren't rendered.

My loaded DOM look like this

[image]

I cannot expand the header html, like it wasn't properly loaded, whereas my `<demo-page>` component was loaded correctly.

Any advice, why the header/footer pair was not loaded up correctly?

Comment: Have you imported the header and footer components at the top of the page?

Comment: yep, both are imported

Comment: Anyone have idea how to restrict header and footers with in the login page. My home page is login page and after login only I need to display headers and footers in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong component selectors were used.
Issue resolved